# How to install drush extension / addon globally?

Tags: drush, installation

I want to install [drush-toolbox](https://github.com/zroger/drush-toolbox) project globaly on my linux server box so all users can use it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it in `/usr/share/drush/commands` for global accessibility.  On Windows, Drush will look in the folder named `Drush/share/drush/commands` inside the location specified by the `ALLUSERSPROFILE` environment variable.

After adding new commands, you will need to run `drush cc drush` to clear the Drush command cache, so that Drush will once again scan its command searchpath.

Comment: Not works for today versions.

Comment: /usr/share/drush/commands is still working fine with Drush 8; I just tested to confirm. Perhaps you did not clear your cache after adding new commands? I updated the answer to include this advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify your own directory for Drush modules/commands by drushrc.php:

```
$options['include'] = array('/path/to/commands','/path2/to/more/commands');
```

This file could be placed in several directories:

1. Drupal site folder (e.g. sites/{default|example.com}/drushrc.php).
2. Drupal sites/all/drush folder.
3. In any location, as specified by the --config (-c) option.
4. User's .drush folder (i.e. ~/.drush/drushrc.php).
5. System wide configuration folder (e.g. /etc/drush/drushrc.php).

More useful informations can be found in [example.drushrc.php](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!examples!example.drushrc.php/7).

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of `drush` (6.2 here) are installed with [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/), the new PHP dependency manager. So the installation of an additional command is now like this, in your case:

1. Go to the installation directory for `drush` commands:

   ```
   cd [drupal-site-docroot]/vendor/drush/drush/commands
   ```

   This assumes the default case where `composer` installed `drush` for each of your Drupal sites separately (it can also install it once per user, or system-wide – I prefer the latter).
2. Download, unpack and clean up:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/zroger/drush-toolbox/archive/master.zip;
   unzip master.zip;
   mv drush-toolbox-master drush-toolbox;
   rm master.zip;
   ```
3. Clear the commandfile cache to register the new command:

   ```
   drush cc drush
   ```

Comment: This installs Drush command only for one site, not globally for all users.

Comment: It is not advisable to manually place files inside the vendor directory, as composer will rewrite that location, e.g. on `composer update`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need it for your local user on Linux, then put plugin into

```
~/.drush/commands
```